# Generate hash from chunked file

Tags: java, hash, cryptography, bouncycastle, message-digest

I'm programming a web service for uploading long files. The client sends the chunks whenever it wants. I need to calculate the hash of this file while theese chunks are received.

I've seen that you can do somenthing like this:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
MessageDigest sha =  MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");

FileInputStream inp = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\season4_mlp.rar"));

int n;
while((n = inp.read(buf)) > 0)
    sha.update(buf, 0, n);

byte hash[] = sha.digest();
```

The problem is that I need to do this with different chunks of the same file and I don't know when they are going to come. **I would need to keep the state of this hash calculation**.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't require BouncyCastle, and unless you've jiggered your provider list doesn't use it at all. But if you mean you want to hash the data chunks out of order, you can't do that, not with JCE nor with BC LWAPI, because that's altering the data which is exactly what any decent crypto-hash and even SHA1 is designed to prevent.

Comment: I will work the hash out using the chunks in order. The question it's been edited for better undestanding... In the example I have `MessageDigest sha` that it's used to generate the final hash. The point is that there is a gap between one chunk and the next one and so I have to keep the state of `MessageDigest sha` until I have all the data and then I can do `byte hash[] = sha.digest();`

Comment: The MessageDigest objects retains all the necessary state. That's why there's an `update()` method.

Comment: It's a web service that receives file chunks of the same file in different requests. This means that I have to maintain the state of `MessageDigest sha` in a safe way between requests until I can do `byte hash[] = sha.digest();`